# Progress view in Local Notification

Tags: ios, uiprogressview, localnotification

Is there any way to add progress view in local notification body ?
I want to show a progress view for an upload, in notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From iOS 10 you can use UNUserNotification framework for creating custom notification interfaces. Please check the link [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251).

Comment: Then I don't think it will be possible

Comment: Any third party library or something ??

Comment: I think apple doesn't support the same on lower versions, so no libraries will be available

Comment: I didn't get any as well.

Comment: Thanks Vaisakh Vinod :) for your precious time and answers.

Comment: @Sudha My pleasure  :)